# communication between chrome extension and desktop app?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome

I am developing a chrome extension which needs to communicate with a desktop app (non-web).  The app uses winsocks so ideally the chrome extension should use some raw socket API for input/output.
The socket API seems still experimental, though.  What are my other options?
In a similar Firefox extension,  I used nsISocketTransportService, nsIScriptableInputStream and nsIInputStreamPump to achieve the purpose.
I am looking for some equivalent in chrome.  Thanks.